# problem on odd function

Tags: calculus, integration

We know that $\int^a_{-a}f(x)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} = 0$ when $f(x)$ is an odd function. But, $\int^1_{-1}\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}$ = 3 even though $\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}$ is an odd function. Why?

Comment: Clarify me if I'm wrong, but if we are integrating from $x=-1$ to $x=1$, we pass through $x=0$?  And that's not too friendly for simple calculations.

Answer (score 4):

No. This function isn't continuous, less defined at zero. The above result holds only when $f \in \mathcal{C}([-a, a])$. The function you've chosen here isn't continuous at zero.

Answer (score 0):

The integral you have written is the sum of two improper integrals, which no one has mentioned and may help clear up confusion.